# Doubly linked list and how to move the iterator to the next node

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have to build a Deque list and inside the the Deque list, it has a function call find, to find the value inside the list. But I'm having problem to try to move the iter over to the next node if that node does not contain the value that I am searching for. Her is the snippet of my find function:

```
unique_ptr<DequeIterator<E>> find(E match)
{
    assert(!is_empty());
    bool is_found = true;

        // set the pointer point to the first node from the beginning        
    unique_ptr<DequeIterator<E>> iter(iter_begin());

    while(iter->node()->value() != match)
    {
                // here is I want to move the iter position
                // over to the next node
        iter->next();
                // print out the value at the node to re-check if
                // it matches
        cout << iter->node()->value() << endl;
    }

    if(is_found)
    {
        cout << "found" << iter->node()->value() << endl;

    }
    else
        cout << "no match" << endl;
    return iter;
}


unique_ptr<DequeIterator<E>> iter_begin()
{       
        // _head is set to nullptr inside the constructor
    return unique_ptr<DequeIterator<E>>(new DequeIterator<E>(_head));
}
```

**DequeIterator class**

```
template<class E>
class DequeIterator {
public:
  // You may need to modify this class. Feel free to modify the definitions of
  // these functions, or add new member functions.

  DequeIterator(DNode<E>* node) {
    _node = node;
  }

  bool at_end() {
    return _node == nullptr;
  }

  E value() {
    assert(!at_end());
    return _node->value();
  }

  void set_value(E x) {
    assert(!at_end());
    _node->set_value(x);
  }

  void next() {
    assert(!at_end());
    _node = _node->next();
  }

  DNode<E>* node() { return _node; }

private:
  DNode<E>* _node;
};
```

**This is my DNode class**

```
template<class E>
class DNode {
public:
  DNode(DNode<E>* prev, E value, DNode<E>* next) {
    _value = value;
    _prev = prev;
    _next = next;
    dnode_census++;
  }

  ~DNode() {
    dnode_census--;
  }

  // The program crashes right here
  // after it goes into the E value()
  E value() { return _value; }
  void set_value(E value) { _value = value; }
  DNode<E>* prev() { return _prev; }
  void set_prev(DNode<E>* prev) { _prev = prev; }
  DNode<E>* next() { return _next; }
  void set_next(DNode<E>* next) { _next = next; }

private:
  E _value;
  DNode<E> *_prev;
  DNode<E> *_next;
};
```

**Deque class**

```
template<class E>
class Deque {
public:

Deque()
{
    _head = 0;
    _size = 0;
    _tail = 0;
}

  ~Deque() {
    clear();
  }

  // Make the deque empty. O(n) time.
  void clear() {
    while (!is_empty())
      erase_back();
  }

  // Return the current size of the deque. O(1) time.
  int size() {
    return _size;
  }

  // Return true when the deque is empty. O(1) time.
  bool is_empty() {
    return (size() == 0);
  }


unique_ptr<DequeIterator<E>> iter_begin()
{
    return unique_ptr<DequeIterator<E>>(new DequeIterator<E>(_head));
}

unique_ptr<DequeIterator<E>> iter_at(int index)
{
    assert((index >= 0) && (index <= size()));
    unique_ptr<DequeIterator<E>> iter(iter_begin());
    for(int j = 0; j < index; j++)
        iter->next();
    return iter;
}

E front()
{
    assert(!is_empty());
    return _head->value();
}


E back()
{
    assert(!is_empty());
    return _tail->value();
}


void insert_after(DequeIterator<E>& iter, E x)
{
    if(_size == 0)
    {
        insert_front(x);
    }
    else
    {
        assert(!iter.at_end());
        DNode<E>* temp = new DNode<E>(iter.node(), x, iter.node()->next());
        iter.node()->next()->set_next(temp);
        iter.node()->next()->set_prev(temp);
    }

    _size++;    
}

void insert_before(DequeIterator<E>& iter, E x)
{
    if(_size == 0)
    {
        insert_front(x);
    }
    else
    {
        assert(!is_empty());
        DNode<E>* temp2 = new DNode<E>(iter.node()->prev(), x, iter.node());
        (iter.node()->prev())->set_next(temp2);
        (iter.node()->prev())->set_prev(temp2);
    }
    _size++;    
}

void insert_front(E x)
{
    if(is_empty())
    {
        DNode<E>* temp = new DNode<E>(nullptr, x, nullptr);
        _head = temp;
        _tail = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        DNode<E>* temp = _head;
        DNode<E>* temp2 = new DNode<E>(nullptr, x, temp);
        _head = temp2;
    }
    _size++;
}


void insert_back(E x)
{
    if(is_empty())
    {
        insert_front(x);
    }
    else
    {
        assert(!is_empty());
        DNode<E>* temp = new DNode<E>(_tail, x, nullptr);
        _tail = temp;
        _size++;
        if(_size > 1)
            cout << _tail->prev()->value() << endl;
    }

}

void erase(DequeIterator<E>& iter)
{
    assert((!is_empty()) || !iter.at_end());

    DNode<E>* temp = iter.node();
    temp->next()->set_prev(temp->prev());
    temp->prev()->set_next(temp->next());

    delete iter.node()->next();
    _size--;
}

void erase_front()
{
    assert(!is_empty());
    DNode<E>* temp = _head;
    _head = temp->next();
    delete temp;
    _size--;

}


void erase_back()
{
    assert(!is_empty());
    DNode<E>* temp = _tail;
    _tail = temp->prev();
    delete temp;
    _size--;
}


unique_ptr<DequeIterator<E>> find(E match)
{
    assert(!is_empty());
    bool is_found = true;

    unique_ptr<DequeIterator<E>> iter(iter_begin());

    while(iter->value() != match)
    {
        iter->next();
        cout << iter->value() << endl;
    }

    if(is_found)
    {
        cout << "found" << iter->node()->value() << endl;

    }
    else
        cout << "no match" << endl;
    return iter;
}


 // Return the element value at position index, which must be
 // valid. O(n) time.
E get(int index) 
{
    assert((index >= 0) && (index < size()));

    unique_ptr<DequeIterator<E>> iter(iter_begin());

    for(int j = 0; j < index; j++)
        iter->next();
        return iter->node()->value();
}

void meld(Deque<E>& other)
{

}

private:
   DNode<E>* _head;
  DNode<E>* _tail;
  int _size;
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main() {
  assert_no_leak(0);

  // Element objects to reuse. All upper case letters of the alphabet.
  //const int N = 5;
  const int N = 26;
  char letters[N];
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    letters[i] = 'A' + i;

  // Now there are a series of unit tests. Each test checks a few
  // related member functions. The tests use assert(...) to look for
  // bugs, so if one of these assertions fails, that indicates a bug
  // in your deque code.

  print_test_title("Deque constructor");
  unique_ptr<Deque<char>> q(new Deque<char>());
  assert_no_leak(0);

  print_test_title("Deque::size");
  assert(q->size() == 0);

  print_test_title("Deque::is_empty");
  assert(q->is_empty());

  print_test_title("Deque::insert_back");
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    assert(q->size() == i);
    assert_no_leak(i);

    q->insert_back(letters[i]);

    assert(!q->is_empty());
    assert(q->size() == (i+1));
    assert_no_leak(i+1);
  }




  print_test_title("iteration");
  unique_ptr<DequeIterator<char>> iter(q->iter_begin());
  assert(!iter->at_end());
  assert_no_leak(N);
  for (int i = 0; !iter->at_end(); i++, iter->next()) {
    assert(i < N);
    assert(iter->value() == letters[i]);
    assert_no_leak(N);
  }
  assert_no_leak(N);

 /* for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      cout << q->get(i) << endl;*/


  print_test_title("Deque::find");

  iter = q->find('A');
  assert(!iter->at_end());
  assert(iter->value() == 'A');
  assert_no_leak(N);

  **// This is where I got the unhandled exception**
  iter =  q->find('T');
  assert(!iter->at_end());
  assert(iter->value() == 'T');
  assert_no_leak(N);

  iter = q->find('?');
  assert(iter->at_end());
  assert_no_leak(N);

  print_test_title("Deque::get");
  for (int index = 0; index < N; index++) {
    assert(q->get(index) == letters[index]);
    assert_no_leak(N);
  }

  print_test_title("Deque::front");
  assert(q->front() == 'C');
  assert_no_leak(N);

  print_test_title("Deque::back");
  assert(q->back() == 'Z');
  assert_no_leak(N);

  print_test_title("Deque::erase_front");
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    assert(q->front() == letters[i]);
    assert(q->size() == (N-i));
    assert_no_leak(N-i);
    q->erase_front();
  }
  assert(q->is_empty());
  assert_no_leak(0);

  print_test_title("Deque::erase_back");
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    q->insert_back(letters[i]);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    assert(q->back() == letters[N-i-1]);
    assert(q->size() == (N-i));
    assert_no_leak(N-i);
    q->erase_back();
  }
  assert(q->is_empty());
  assert_no_leak(0);

  print_test_title("Deque::insert_front");
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    q->insert_front(letters[i]);
    assert(q->front() == letters[i]);
    assert(q->size() == (i+1));
    assert_no_leak(i+1);
  }
  assert(q->size() == N);
  assert_no_leak(N);

  print_test_title("Deque::clear");
  q->clear();
  assert(q->is_empty());
  assert_no_leak(0);
  for (int size = 0; size <= N; size++) {
    assert(q->is_empty());
    assert_no_leak(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      q->insert_back(letters[i]);

    assert(q->size() == size);
    assert_no_leak(size);

    q->clear();
    assert(q->is_empty());
    assert_no_leak(0);
  }

  print_test_title("insert_after, insert_before, erase");
  assert(q->is_empty());
  iter = q->iter_begin(); // iter is at end of empty queue
  q->insert_before(*iter, 'X');
  assert(queue_equals_string(*q, "X"));
  assert_no_leak(1);
  iter = q->iter_begin(); // iter is at start of queue with 1 element
  q->insert_after(*iter, 'O');
  assert(queue_equals_string(*q, "XO"));
  assert_no_leak(2);
  q->insert_after(*iter, 'Z');
  assert(queue_equals_string(*q, "XZO"));
  assert_no_leak(3);
  iter->next(); // iter is at second position (Z)
  q->insert_before(*iter, 'C');
  assert(queue_equals_string(*q, "XCZO"));
  assert_no_leak(4);
  q->insert_after(*iter, 'A');
  assert(queue_equals_string(*q, "XCZAO"));
  assert_no_leak(5);
  iter->next(); // iter is at fourth position (A)
  q->erase(*iter); // erase A
  assert(queue_equals_string(*q, "XCZO"));
  assert_no_leak(4);
  iter = q->iter_begin(); // X
  iter->next(); // C
  iter->next(); // Z
  q->erase(*iter); // erase Z
  assert(queue_equals_string(*q, "XCO"));
  assert_no_leak(3);
  q->erase(*q->iter_begin()); // erase X
  assert(queue_equals_string(*q, "CO"));
  assert_no_leak(2);
  iter = q->iter_begin(); // erase O
  iter->next();
  q->erase(*iter);
  assert(queue_equals_string(*q, "C"));
  assert_no_leak(1);
  q->erase(*q->iter_begin()); // erase C
  assert(queue_equals_string(*q, ""));
  assert_no_leak(0);

  print_test_title("Deque::splice");
  assert(q->is_empty());
  assert_no_leak(0);
  unique_ptr<Deque<char>> q2(new Deque<char>());
  assert_no_leak(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    q->insert_back(letters[i]);
    q2->insert_back(letters[i]);
  }
  assert(q->size() == 5);
  assert(q2->size() == 5);
  assert_no_leak(10);
  q->meld(*q2);
  assert(q->size() == 10);
  assert(q2->is_empty());
  assert_no_leak(10);
  assert(queue_equals_string(*q, "ABCDEABCDE"));

  if (DO_PERFORMANCE_TEST) {
    print_test_title("Performance");
    q->clear();
    time_t start = time(nullptr);
    for (int i = 0; i < BIG_N; i++) {
      q->insert_front('A');
      if ((i % 1000) == 0)
        cout << '.';
    }
    time_t stop = time(nullptr);
    assert(q->size() == BIG_N);
    cout << endl
         << "  Elapsed time to insert_front " << BIG_N << " times: " 
         << (stop - start) << " seconds" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your `DequeIterator` at least follow the requirements of the `ForwardIterator` Concept? If so, you should be able to simply increment the iterator: `++iter->node()`.

Comment: I don't have the function forwardIterator inside the DequeIterator class :(

Comment: That's not what I mean. I'm referring to the [`ForwardIterator` Concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator).

Comment: Try as I might, I can not think of a can't-live-without feature of an iterator that would mandate wrapping it in a unique-ptr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not really doing anything with that iterator.  The whole point is you want to change it to point to the next item in the list.

Normally with iterators you would implement `operator++`.  It might look something like this:

```
template <class E>
DequeIterator<E> & DequeIterator::operator++()
{
    _node = _node->next;
    return *this;
}
```

It's not clear why you are allocating your iterators and using `unique_ptr`.  Normally you return iterators by value, and their internals are very simple (a pointer or two).  No need to allocate them on the heap.

---

After seeing your iterator code, it seems you're just using the wrong `next()`.  You're calling it on the current node, rather than the iterator:

```
iter->node()->next();   // incorrect
iter->next();           // correct
```

---

As suggested by *WhozCraig* in the comments:

> the difference between this iterator and a post-increment matching
>   implementation with its by-value temp-copy return may be warranted for
>   the casual reader.

The `++` operation I gave was the prefix operator, meaning you need to do `++*iter`.  If you want to do `(*iter)++`, you need a postfix operator:

```
template <class E> DequeIterator<E> DequeIterator::operator++(int) {
    DequeIterator<E> temp(*this);
    _node = _node->next;
    return temp;
}
```

And since your list is double-linked, you might like to provide the appropriate `--` prefix and postfix operators.

Comment: +1 Not that I see the OP getting there anytime soon, but the difference between this iterator and a post-increment matching implementation with its by-value temp-copy return may be warranted for the casual reader.

Comment: so I change my iter->next(), I got a unhandled exception right at E value() function inside the DequeIterator class :(

Comment: The thing is my professor required us to do unique pointer for the iter instead of raw pointer :(

Comment: @HoangMinh What I'm trying to say is you shouldn't be using a pointer for your iterator at all.  It's very unusual.

Comment: Regarding the exception, it's possible that your `Deque` is not built correctly.  Or perhaps you're at the end of the list after incrementing.  You never check - you increment first, and then just try to get the value, even if the iterator is now pointing to `nullptr`.  There is an `assert` there.  Is that firing?

Comment: It should not be at the end. What I was doing is I try to insert all the letter from A to Z to the list. As I run check for all the characters in there, it only goes past the first letter A, and it crash as soon as it hit the second letter

Comment: Then take my first suspicion - that you did not construct your `Deque` correctly.  Only you can test this.  If you're not comfortable with the debugger, use `cout` strategically to find out whether certain values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: @HoangMinh You don't have to use a raw pointer. You can wrap the internal node smart pointers, and use one in the iterator as well. Honestly the only tricky part of a smart pointer link chain is the clearing without creating a call-stack N-items deep (and even that, though not intuitive is doable). I agree about the no-raw-pointers, but that doesn't me your iterator should be dynamically allocated and wrapped by a smart pointer.

Comment: @paddy: I posted my DNode class as well, could you take a look and see what it goes wrong ?

Comment: That class doesn't show me anything.  It's how you're using it that's important.  Show the code that builds the list.

Comment: @paddy: just add the main.cpp file in there. I also notice where I got the exception error as well. Would you please take a look at ? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you never do any linking in `insert_back`.  Your node class doesn't do anything intelligent, so it's up to the caller to link.  Your other functions seem to do this, but in that particular function you forgot to do `_tail->set_next(temp);`.  You need to do something similar with the prev pointer in the non-empty case of `insert_front`.  I would have just implemented it properly in the node constructor and relieve the caller of the responsibility.

Comment: If you have further questions, it might be more fruitful to post a new question.  I'm just about to head away for the weekend and won't be anywhere near computers.  Good luck.

Comment: @paddy: thanks a lot for your help. I mean it. You saved my day. I'll figure out the rest by myself then. Have a good weekend there.