# Search in doubly linked list

Tags: c++, deque

I'm having problem on how to get out of the loop in a doubly linked list when it gets to the end of the deque. If there is an element in the deque, it will return the iter position. If not, it will return the iterator at the end of the deque. I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you

Here is my search function

```
unique_ptr<DequeIterator<E>> find(E match)
{
    assert(!is_empty());

        // the iter will begin from the head.
    unique_ptr<DequeIterator<E>> iter(iter_begin());

        // Here is where I do not know how to get it quit when 
        // it gets to the end of the deque.
        // ALSO it needs to check the value at the end of
        // the deque before it quits too.
    while(iter->value() != match)
    {
        iter->next();
    }
    return iter;
}
```

Comment: Side note: Are you ___really___ sure you want to use a smart pointer on already allocated and managed data?

Comment: It's not something that I want to, but it's what my professor required us to do :(

Comment: @Zeta Believe me, [this code has been through plenty of ringers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719529/doubly-linked-list-and-how-to-move-the-iterator-to-the-next-node).

Comment: Bit of a trend these days for people using c++ to refuse to manage heap memory, and bung smart pointers everywhere and assume it'll all be ok.  (In academia at least.)

Comment: If your prof isn't using a standard library iterator, you really need to supply the interface for `DequeIterator`.

Comment: You're professor needs to switch to decaf. I cannot think of a single feature that an iterator needs that is delivered by wrapping it in dynamic memory ala smart pointers. Seriously. *not one*. An iterator should be a copy-assignable *object*. the nodes it is iterating can be smart pointer-referenced via members of the iterator, but there is *zero* reason to do it the way your prof said, if indeed this is examplary of his/her instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely just something like:

```
while( iter != iter_end() && 
       iter->value() != match )
{
    iter->next();
}

return iter;
```

Comment: would it skip the last node, and won't check its value to see if it's matched ?

Comment: never mind. I'm so dumb. The deque is at end when the last node is nullptr. Thanks for your help

Comment: Typically in such containers, `end()` doesn't return the last node but the "null" node after it.  Also, typically in an empty list `begin() == end()` would be true.  The reason for this being to allow code like that what I posted.  :-)